# connection.getContentLength() in android returns -1

Tags: java, android, kotlin

This is my kotlin code inside `override fun doInBackground`

```
val url = URL(f_url[0])
        val connection = url.openConnection()
        connection.connect()
        // getting file length
        val lengthOfFile = connection.getContentLength()

        println(lengthOfFile.toString()+" is the length")// this returns -1
```

And this is my java code for the same inside `protected String doInBackground(String... arg0)`

```
URL url = new URL(downLoadUrl);
            URLConnection conection = url.openConnection();
            conection.connect();
            // this will be useful so that you can show a tipical 0-100% progress bar
            int lenghtOfFile = conection.getContentLength();// also returns -1
```

I noticed this error one or two months before.

Because of this problem i cannot implement horizontal progress bar

I wrote the same code as a  pure java standalone class and tested separately (without android) and was working fine

This error is only appearing in Android both Kotlin and Java

Please help

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: the length returns as -1

Comment: It's not an error exactly. Check if the download URL is valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not reading the input stream.  This should work:

```
val url = URL("https://www.google.com")
val connection = url.openConnection() as? HttpURLConnection ?: return
connection.connect()

val inputStream = connection.inputStream
val content = inputStream.bufferedReader().use { it.readText() }

println("${content.length} is the length")
```

Comment: This answer works in kotlin, but i am still perplexed because of the fact that my this behavior occured suddenly in my code. Because it was working fine till a couple of months before